# error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int (*)(const void*, const void*)'

Tags: c

While compiling my C file, I am getting the below error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int (*)(const void*, const void*)'
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void* bsearch(int (*)(const void*, const void*))'
```

Below are some code snippets:

```
static int
testfucn(const char *func, const teststruct *array)
{
  return (strcmp(func, array->name));
}

int
test(char *fcn)
{
    if (bsearch((void*)testfucn))
        return(1);
    else
        return(0);
}
```

Error is coming for the line `bsearch((void*)testfucn)`

Could you please suggest what is wrong with this code and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Also, what `bsearch` function are you using? Apparently its not the [standard `bsearch` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit - you're passing in a `void*` (obtained by your explicit cast) while the function expects an `int (*)(const void*, const void*)`. There is no implicit conversion from 'pointer to `void`' to 'pointer to a function', hence the error.

I believe you could get away with casting the function to the requested type:

```
bsearch((int (*)(const void*, const void*)testfucn);
```

However, note that while it might (appear to) work in practice, it would invoke Undefined Behaviour.

The correct, type-safe solution is to actually declare a function with the appropriate signature, possibly as a wrapper around your real function:

```
static int
testfucn_for_bsearch(const void *func, const void *array)
{
  return testfucn(func, array);
}

/* ... */

bsearch(testfucn_for_bsearch);
```

Comment: IIRC, calling a function cast to a different type is undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo Fair enough, re-worded

Comment: Thanks @Angrew. Adding (int (*)(const void*, const void*)) worked !!

Comment: @user1138143 Be aware that that one is a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cast. You can't cast between data (`void *`) and function pointers, and the argument should be a function pointer.

Also fix your function's signature, it doesn't match the expected signature of a `bsearch()` callback. See [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch) for the proper signature.